# Is the current of a SPAD a digital signal? (Question about Avalanche process)

Tags: optics, semiconductor-physics, photoelectric-effect

I understand that when a [Single Photon Avalanche Diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-photon_avalanche_diode) (SPAD) is biased and a photon hits it, an avalanche process is activated that cause a current. What happens if two photons hit it? Will the process be more intense and there will be a proportionally higher current? Or is it simply either on or off?
I'm trying to figure out the advantage of an [Silicon Photomultiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_photomultiplier) (SiPM) comparing to a single SPAD with a high gain. I had a suspicion that this might be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SiPM is just an array of SPADs whose outputs are summed. A SPAD is just an [Avalanche Photodiode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_photodiode) operated in Geiger mode (like a [Geiger-Muller tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger%E2%80%93M%C3%BCller_tube)) where any detectable signal produces the same sized avalanche output. So yes, a SPAD does produce a "digital" on/off signal that is same size whether one or two or more photons hit it simultaneously.  As long as  multiple simultaneous photons hit different SPAD pixels in a SiPM, the output of the SiPM will be proportional to the number of photons.